# Swap black and white chec box

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I need to set the black and white swap function in forge viewer, for the user to be able to swap the 2D document visualization to black or white background.

When I set this function in the js code, only the black and white layers swap. The background remains white.

Can anybody help?

[image: screen shot of this issue]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for AutoCAD 2D drawings, as per [documentation](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/reference/javascript/guiviewer3d/):

> **setSwapBlackAndWhite(value)**
>
> AutoCAD drawings are commonly displayed with white lines on a black
>   background. Setting reverse swaps (just) these two colors.

And the code should look like:

```
viewer.setSwapBlackAndWhite(true)  // background black
viewer.setSwapBlackAndWhite(false) // background white
```

Comment: Hello Augusto, this is what the viewer API does.. however, in our application, this is only being applyed to layers, not to the background, which is always white. Can you help me?

Comment: The issue was happening because we're working with an aold version of the viewer. Just by pushing it's version to the latest: 2.14, the issue was solved.

Answer (score 0):

To set the color of the 'surrounding' background, try using this...

`viewer.setBackgroundColor(0,0,0,0,0,0);`

If you want a 'gradient' background from say, blue at the top, down to red at the bottom, try this...

`viewer.setBackgroundColor(0,0,255,255,0,0);`

So, the specification looks like this:

`viewer.setBackgroundColor(colorTopRed,colorTopGreen,colorTopBlue, colorBottomRed, colorBottomGreen, colorBottomBlue);`

Click [here](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/reference/javascript/viewer3d/#setactivenavigationtool-toolname) for the full spec.